# Delete row and adds to another sheet base on unique values in a column

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Can anyone help with this?
I have reviewed the other questions on this site, but have not found a satisfactory answer.

I have a sheet receiving responses from a form - IF Column F(Column 6) of the new form submission is the same value as an existing entry in Column F, I want to move the old entry row to an archive sheet (Deleting them from this sheet). This would leave the response sheet with only unique entries in Column F.

The reason for this is that I only want to see current entries, but save older entries in an archive.

Would be great if someone could help with this.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What kind of a value is column F

Comment: Sorry the 6th column

Comment: That's column F. What type of value is it?

Comment: sorry my first statement was a bit mixed up. Yes if new row add has the same number in col 6 I want the script to remove all rows that was submitted before (lower row numbers) to delete and move. So the response sheet would only show the the rows which column 6 (F) is unique.

Answer (score 0):

If we want to have:

1. a sheet of all responses (archive)
   and
2. a sheet of only the newest responses of each kind (determined by Column F)

I recommend keeping the response sheet as it is, using the response sheet as the "archive" and then designating a NEW sheet to be the "live" list of only new responses. It is troublesome to mutate the form response sheet and this should be kept only as an archive and not edited.

Here's a solution which uses the response sheet as the "archive" and designates a new sheet to use as the "live" view of newest responses.

First you must create a form submit trigger:
On Script Editor page, click Edit > Current Project's Triggers
Add a trigger and change event type to: On form submit,
and make sure the correct function is selected at the top (myFunction in this case)

Use this script:

```
function myFunction(e) {
  //  //Use this commented section to refer to a live sheet in another Spreadsheet
  //  let url = "[Enter url for Spreadsheet here]"
  //  let liveSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url).getSheets()[0];
  let liveSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets()[1];
  let responseSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();  
  let newRow = responseSheet.getActiveRange().getRow();
  let liveLastRow = liveSheet.getLastRow();
  let responseLastColumn = responseSheet.getLastColumn();
  let matchColumn = 6;
  //Get list of entries in match column to find duplicates, 
  //Initialization and IF statement are in case there are 0 rows.
  let oldEntries = [];
  console.log(liveLastRow, liveLastRow > 0);
  if (liveLastRow > 0) {
  oldEntries = liveSheet.getRange(1, matchColumn, liveLastRow, 1).getValues();
  }
  //Load in data from new response entry
  let newEntry = responseSheet.getRange(newRow, 1, 1,  responseLastColumn).getValues()[0];
  console.log("Existing rows in live sheet: ", oldEntries.length, "\nNew Entry: ", newEntry);
  console.log("Scanning old entries for duplicate...");
  //Loop through all old entries to search for match
  for (entry = 0; entry < oldEntries.length; entry++) {
    console.log("Is this a match in entry row #", (entry+1), "? \n", String(newEntry[matchColumn-1]), String(oldEntries[entry][0]));
    //If matches existing row
    if (String(newEntry[matchColumn-1]) === String(oldEntries[entry])) {
      console.log("Found a match!", "Copying new entry to row: ", (entry + 1), "with ", newEntry.length, "columns");
      //Copy to Live sheet
      liveSheet.getRange((entry + 1), 1, 1, newEntry.length).setValues([newEntry]);
      console.log("Replaced old entry ", oldEntries[entry][0], " with new entry:", newEntry);
      console.log("done :)");
      return
    }
    console.log("No Match...");
  }
  //If no existing entry, then just append the new entry to bottom of list.
  console.log("Appending new entry to bottom of live sheet...");
  liveSheet.appendRow(newEntry);
  console.log("done :)");
}
```

I made a test form and ran it. Works.
Logic is as follows:
Does this entry exist on the live sheet already?
If yes > replace that entry with this new one,
If no > append new entry to bottom of list.